# Recursive string search in DOM-Nodes using a generator Raw

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am currently trying to wrap my head around es6 generators/iterators, so I wrote a function searching a node for a specific teststring and returning it.

In this text (taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)), the first call searching for `'Returns a'` is a hit, but the second one returns `false` in practice (in this case it, returns the script tag since the string is found in the script tag appended to the HTML in jsfiddle).

```js
/*
 * @param {HTMLElement}
 * @yields {Iterable.<*>}
 */
function* _deepTraverseElements (node) {
    if (!node) {
        return;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
        const val = node;
        yield val.children[i];
        if (val.children) {
            yield* _deepTraverseElements(val.children[i]);
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Useage: findElementByInnerText('body', 'Hello World');
 * @param {string} selector
 * @param {string} String the element should contain
 * @returns {(boolean)|(HTMLElement)} DOM-Element that contains the string. Returns false If none is found
 */

const findElementByInnerText = (selector, text) => {
    const parent = document.querySelector(selector);
    _deepTraverseElements(parent);
    for (const element of _deepTraverseElements(parent)) {
        if (!element.childNodes[0] || element.childNodes[0].nodeType !== 3) continue;
        if (element.childNodes[0].data.indexOf(text) !== -1) return element;
    }
    return false;
};

console.log(findElementByInnerText('body', 'Returns a'));
console.log(findElementByInnerText('body', 'interface from which a number'));
```

```html
<p><strong><code>Node</code></strong> is an interface from which a number of DOM API object types inherit; it allows these various types to be treated similarly, for example inheriting the same set of methods, or being tested in the same way.</p>

<dl>
 <dt><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURI" title="The Node.baseURI read-only property returns the absolute base URL of a node."><code>Node.baseURI</code></a> <span class="inlineIndicator readOnly readOnlyInline" title="This value may not be changed.">Read only </span></dt>
 <dd>Returns a <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString" title="DOMString is a UTF-16 String. As JavaScript already uses such strings, DOMString is mapped directly to a String."><code>DOMString</code></a> representing the base URL. The concept of base URL changes from one language to another; in HTML, it corresponds to the protocol, the domain name and the directory structure, that is all until the last <code>'/'</code>.</dd>
 <dt><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURIObject" title="The Node.baseURIObject property returns the nsIURI representing the node's (typically a document or an element) base URL. It's similar to Node.baseURI, except it returns an nsIURI instead of a string."><code>Node.baseURIObject</code></a> <span title="This API has not been standardized."><i class="icon-warning-sign"> </i></span> </dt>
 <dd>(Not available to web content.) The read-only <code><a href="/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIURI" title="">nsIURI</a></code> object representing the base URI for the element.</dd>
 <dt><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes" title="The Node.childNodes read-only property returns a live collection of child nodes of the given element where the first child node is assigned index 0."><code>Node.childNodes</code></a> <span class="inlineIndicator readOnly readOnlyInline" title="This value may not be changed.">Read only </span></dt>
 <dd>Returns a live <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList" title="NodeList objects are collections of nodes such as those returned by properties such as Node.childNodes and the document.querySelectorAll() method."><code>NodeList</code></a> containing all the children of this node. <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList" title="NodeList objects are collections of nodes such as those returned by properties such as Node.childNodes and the document.querySelectorAll() method."><code>NodeList</code></a> being live means that if the children of the <code>Node</code> change, the <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList" title="NodeList objects are collections of nodes such as those returned by properties such as Node.childNodes and the document.querySelectorAll() method."><code>NodeList</code></a> object is automatically updated.</dd>
 <dt><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild" title="The Node.firstChild read-only property returns the node's first child in the tree, or null if the node has no children."><code>Node.firstChild</code></a> <span class="inlineIndicator readOnly readOnlyInline" title="This value may not be changed.">Read only </span></dt>
 <dd>Returns a <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node" title="Node is an interface from which a number of DOM API object types inherit; it allows these various types to be treated similarly, for example inheriting the same set of methods, or being tested in the same way."><code>Node</code></a> representing the first direct child node of the node, or <code>null</code> if the node has no child.</dd>
 <dt><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild" title="The Node.lastChild read-only property returns the last child of the node. If its parent is an element, then the child is generally an element node, a text node, or a comment node. It returns null if there are no child elements."><code>Node.lastChild</code></a> <span class="inlineIndicator readOnly readOnlyInline" title="This value may not be changed.">Read only </span></dt>
 <dd>Returns a <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node" title="Node is an interface from which a number of DOM API object types inherit; it allows these various types to be treated similarly, for example inheriting the same set of methods, or being tested in the same way."><code>Node</code></a> representing the last direct child node of the node, or <code>null</code> if the node has no child.</dd>
 <dt><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling" title="The Node.nextSibling read-only property returns the node immediately following the specified one in its parent's childNodes list, or null if the specified node is the last node in that list."><code>Node.nextSibling</code></a> <span class="inlineIndicator readOnly readOnlyInline" title="This value may not be changed.">Read only </span></dt>
 <dd>Returns a <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node" title="Node is an interface from which a number of DOM API object types inherit; it allows these various types to be treated similarly, for example inheriting the same set of methods, or being tested in the same way."><code>Node</code></a> representing the next node in the tree, or <code>null</code> if there isn't such node.</dd>
 <dt><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName" title="The Node.nodeName read-only property returns the name of the current node as a string."><code>Node.nodeName</code></a> <span class="inlineIndicator readOnly readOnlyInline" title="This value may not be changed.">Read only </span></dt>
 <dd>Returns a <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString" title="DOMString is a UTF-16 String. As JavaScript already uses such strings, DOMString is mapped directly to a String."><code>DOMString</code></a> containing the name of the <code>Node</code>. The structure of the name will differ with the node type. E.g. An <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement" title="The HTMLElement interface represents any HTML element. Some elements directly implement this interface, others implement it via an interface that inherits it."><code>HTMLElement</code></a> will contain the name of the corresponding tag, like <code>'audio'</code> for an <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement" title="The HTMLAudioElement interface provides access to the properties of <audio> elements, as well as methods to manipulate them. It derives from the HTMLMediaElement interface."><code>HTMLAudioElement</code></a>, a <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text" title="The Text interface represents the textual content of Element or Attr.&nbsp; If an element has no markup within its content, it has a single child implementing Text that contains the element's text.&nbsp; However, if the element contains markup, it is parsed into information items and Text nodes that form its children."><code>Text</code></a> node will have the <code>'#text'</code> string, or a <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document" title="The Document interface represents any web page loaded in the browser and serves as an entry point into the web page's content, which is the DOM tree."><code>Document</code></a> node will have the <code>'#document'</code> string.</dd>
 <dt><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodePrincipal" title="The documentation about this has not yet been written; please consider contributing!"><code>Node.nodePrincipal</code></a> <span title="This API has not been standardized."><i class="icon-warning-sign"> </i></span></dt>
 <dd>A <code><a href="/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPrincipal" title="">nsIPrincipal</a></code> representing the node principal.</dd>
 <dt><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType" title="The read-only Node.nodeType property that represents the type of the node."><code>Node.nodeType</code></a><span class="inlineIndicator readOnly readOnlyInline" title="This value may not be changed.">Read only </span></dt>
 <dd>Returns an <code>unsigned short</code> representing the type of the node. Possible values are:
 <table class="standard-table">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Value</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><code>ELEMENT_NODE</code></td>
    <td><code>1</code></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><code>ATTRIBUTE_NODE</code> <span title="This deprecated API should no longer be used, but will probably still work."><i class="icon-thumbs-down-alt"> </i></span></td>
    <td><code>2</code></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><code>TEXT_NODE</code></td>
    <td><code>3</code></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><code>CDATA_SECTION_NODE</code> <span title="This deprecated API should no longer be used, but will probably still work."><i class="icon-thumbs-down-alt"> </i></span></td>
    <td><code>4</code></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><code>ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE</code> <span title="This deprecated API should no longer be used, but will probably still work."><i class="icon-thumbs-down-alt"> </i></span></td>
    <td><code>5</code></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><code>ENTITY_NODE</code> <span title="This deprecated API should no longer be used, but will probably still work."><i class="icon-thumbs-down-alt"> </i></span></td>
    <td><code>6</code></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><code>PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE</code></td>
    <td><code>7</code></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><code>COMMENT_NODE</code></td>
    <td><code>8</code></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><code>DOCUMENT_NODE</code></td>
    <td><code>9</code></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><code>DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE</code></td>
    <td><code>10</code></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><code>DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE</code></td>
    <td><code>11</code></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><code>NOTATION_NODE</code> <span title="This deprecated API should no longer be used, but will probably still work."><i class="icon-thumbs-down-alt"> </i></span></td>
    <td><code>12</code></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 </dd>
 <dt><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue" title="The Node.nodeValue property returns or sets the value of the current node."><code>Node.nodeValue</code></a></dt>
 <dd>Returns / Sets the value of the current node</dd>
 <dt><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/ownerDocument" title="The Node.ownerDocument read-only property returns the top-level document object for this node."><code>Node.ownerDocument</code></a> <span class="inlineIndicator readOnly readOnlyInline" title="This value may not be changed.">Read only </span></dt>
 <dd>Returns the <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document" title="The Document interface represents any web page loaded in the browser and serves as an entry point into the web page's content, which is the DOM tree."><code>Document</code></a> that this node belongs to. If no document is associated with it, returns <code>null</code>.</dd>
 <dt><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode" title="The Node.parentNode read-only property returns the parent of the specified node in the DOM tree."><code>Node.parentNode</code></a> <span class="inlineIndicator readOnly readOnlyInline" title="This value may not be changed.">Read only </span></dt>
 <dd>Returns a <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node" title="Node is an interface from which a number of DOM API object types inherit; it allows these various types to be treated similarly, for example inheriting the same set of methods, or being tested in the same way."><code>Node</code></a> that is the parent of this node. If there is no such node, like if this node is the top of the tree or if doesn't participate in a tree, this property returns <code>null</code>.</dd>
 <dt><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement" title="The Node.parentElement read-only property returns the DOM node's parent Element, or null if the node either has no parent, or its parent isn't a DOM Element."><code>Node.parentElement</code></a> <span class="inlineIndicator readOnly readOnlyInline" title="This value may not be changed.">Read only </span></dt>
 <dd>Returns an <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element" title="Element is the most general base class from which all objects in a Document inherit. It only has methods and properties common to all kinds of element. More specific classes inherit from Element."><code>Element</code></a> that is the parent of this node. If the node has no parent, or if that parent is not an <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element" title="Element is the most general base class from which all objects in a Document inherit. It only has methods and properties common to all kinds of element. More specific classes inherit from Element."><code>Element</code></a>, this property returns <code>null</code>.</dd>
 <dt><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling" title="The Node.previousSibling read-only property returns the node immediately preceding the specified one in its parent's childNodes list, or null if the specified node is the first in that list."><code>Node.previousSibling</code></a> <span class="inlineIndicator readOnly readOnlyInline" title="This value may not be changed.">Read only </span></dt>
 <dd>Returns a <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node" title="Node is an interface from which a number of DOM API object types inherit; it allows these various types to be treated similarly, for example inheriting the same set of methods, or being tested in the same way."><code>Node</code></a> representing the previous node in the tree, or <code>null</code> if there isn't such node.</dd>
 <dt><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent" title="The Node.textContent&nbsp;property represents the text content of a node and its descendants."><code>Node.textContent</code></a></dt>
 <dd>Returns / Sets the textual content of an element and all its descendants.</dd>
</dl>
```

Expected Output: DOMNode
`<p><strong><code>Node</code></strong> is an interface from which a number of DOM API object types inherit; it allows these various types to be treated similarly, for example inheriting the same set of methods, or being tested in the same way.</p>`

Current Output: `false`

Comment: `val = node;` and `if (val.children)` don't make much sense

Comment: Well `element.childNodes[0]` for that `<p>` element is the `<strong>` element, whose `.nodeType` is not `3` so the `element` is never considered to be returned.

Comment: oh, that makes sense. How do I relieably access the value of these elements aswell then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your `find` function doesn't work because it only looks at the first child of each element, and your generator does weird things as well.

I would recommend to avoid dealing with text nodes, and just use the [`.textContent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to access the text in an element regardless of its substructure. That will also allow you to find search terms across multiple nodes. To get the deepest one (and not always just the whole document that contains the phrase), the generator should use post-order depth first traversal:

```
function* traverseElements(node) {
    if (node.nodeType != 1) return; // only consider Element nodes
    for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++)
        yield* traverseElements(node.children[i]); // get all descendants
    yield node; // afterwards yield node itself
}

function findElementWithText(root, text) {
    for (const element of traverseElements(root))
        if (element.textContent.includes(text))
            return element;
    return null;
}

console.log(findElementWithText(document.body, 'Returns a'));
console.log(findElementWithText(document.body, 'interface from which a number'));
```

Comment: tried it, works like a charm. I don't really understand why, though. Shouldn't the generator yield the `dl` first since it contains the String `'Returns a'`? The `yield*` should push `dl` into the returned iterator first and `<dl>...</dl>` should be returned by the find function in my understanding